# rHighchart in R Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rstudio

I am trying to make an active dashboard in R, and I have made a map of crimes in America:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = "Total crime in America") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: inkomen_crime.xlsx") %>%
  hc_add_series_map(usgeojson, car,
                    name = "state",
                    value = "total_crime",
                    joinBy = c("woename", "state")) %>%
  hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)
```

However, I can't seem to run it in R shiny, with this code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "stateDrop",
              label = "Selecteer een Staat",
              choices = all_states,
              selected = "California",
              multiple=TRUE),

  DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "America")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$America <- renderDataTable({

    population <- data %>%
      filter(State %in% input$stateDrop)

    datatable(data = population)
  })
}
```

I feel like I need to make a reference to the highchart, but I can't find anything online. What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Hi, could you provide all the packages and your data so I can run your chart?

Comment: I am getting this error:

Error in lint(appDir, appFiles, appPrimaryDoc) : 
  Cancelling deployment: invalid project layout.
The project should have one of the following layouts:
1. 'shiny.R' and 'ui.R' in the application base directory,
2. 'shiny.R' and 'www/index.html' in the application base directory,
3. 'app.R' or a single-file Shiny .R file,
4. An R Markdown (.Rmd) document,
5. A static HTML (.html) or PDF (.pdf) document.
6. 'plumber.R' API description .R file
7. 'entrypoint.R' plumber startup script
8. A tensorflow saved model

Comment: I am Highcharts JavaScript developer, we do not support R Highcharter and Shiny - I don't know R well so I will not help you with your errors until I can fully reproduce your chart. For this, I need the list of packages you are using and your data.
If you are just asking about how to run the chart in Shiny, you can find some examples in my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8618934/raf18seb?tab=answers

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput(inputId = "stateDrop",
                label = "Selecteer een Staat",
                choices = all_states,
                selected = "California",
                multiple=TRUE),

    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "America"), 

    highchartOutput(outputId = 'plot')
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$America <- renderDataTable({

        population <- data %>%
            filter(State %in% input$stateDrop)

        datatable(data = population)
    })

    output$plot <- renderHighchart({
        highchart() %>%
            hc_title(text = "Total crime in America") %>%
            hc_subtitle(text = "Source: inkomen_crime.xlsx") %>%
            hc_add_series_map(usgeojson, car,
                              name = "state",
                              value = "total_crime",
                              joinBy = c("woename", "state")) %>%
            hc_mapNavigation(enabled = T)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```